# Connection check works only during Run from Android Studio

Tags: android, network-programming

i have a problem with my application.
I set a service that open a webpage to parse some element.
So i need to check my internet connection before executing the task.
this is my receiver:

```
 package michele.alertsubito;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public Boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
            return reachable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        JsoupAsyncTask task = new JsoupAsyncTask(context);

        if (isOnline()){
            task.execute();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "alert: no connection!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

The problem is that this check start only if my phone is connected to the PC!
If I start my application from my phone (disconnected from the PC) my isOnline always return false and i get "no connection" toast!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to check if your device is connected to the interenet:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```